# rails routes - model relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model which has 2 foreign keys belonging to the same model.

```
 Owner model
   has_many :vehicles
 end
```

Vehicle model has 2 fields owner_id and co_owner_id.

```
 Vehicle model
    belongs_to :owner, :foreign_key => 'owner_id'
 end
```

How do I define the relationship for co_owner_id field? so that I can do something like vehicle.co_owner.firstname

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but shouldnt

```
belongs_to :co_owner, :foreign_key => 'co_owner_id', :class => 'owner'
```

do it?